# Need explanation for use of '%' and '/' to grid buttons with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, grid, tkinter, modulo

The code below is used in a simple calculator I made using Tkinter to implement a simple gui. I am new to Python, and it is basically my first programming language. This is my first stab at creating a gui. The calculator works fine, well almost. The buttons do what they are supposed to so far. My question is this: In the code below I have made row = index%3 and column  = index/3. This places my buttons in a nice 3 x 3 block. However, I used this snippet without fully understanding it. I found it online. I find I can tinker with it to get desired results, but I'm not entirely clear why it works the way it does. I suppose this is basically a math question really. Any clarification would be much appreciated though. Sorry if it's structured oddly, I'm not used to this forum formatting business.

```
self.operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/','%','^','C','M','M+']     
for index in range(9):
  Button(self.opFrame, relief=GROOVE, bg="light yellow", 
    text=self.operators[index], width=3, height=1,
    command=lambda arg=self.operators[index],
    arg2=self.num_dict,
    arg3=self.num_list,
    arg4=self.count : self.buttonClick(arg,arg2,arg3,arg4)).grid(padx=2,pady=2,row=index%3,column=index/3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator yields the remainder from the division of the index by three, so in the nine iterations it will yield *0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2* in this order. In other words, it "loops" over the values 0, 1 and 2 for each iteration.

With `/`, you calculate the floor division of the index by three: *0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2*. This way you move to the next column each three iterations.

It is much easier to see it if you change the order of the operators and arrange `self.operator` like this:

```
self.operators = ['+', '/', 'C',
                  '-', '%', 'M',
                  '*', '^', 'M+']

for index in range(9):
    Button(...).grid(padx=2,pady=2,row=index/3,column=index%3)
```